# How to convert positional data into xml data in wso2 esb

Tags: xml, wso2, esb, smooks

I tried using smooks mediator but no luck.

can anyone help with the guidance or any code snippet for converting positional into xml data in wso2 esb.

positional data:

126164142984982549250  dsadqdsadssfsds 6312654555  456620533  631412478147941949
158465110552332222022  gerjgrengegnsrw 2587566256  785964212  258769651436652365
265784295331333223333  fjkwfweufmnwfvn 6582654257  875662223  698263674123651236

example expected xml output:

```
<root>
    <input>
        <firtstname></firtstname> (postions 1-20)
        <lastname></lastname>     (postions 21-27)
        <age></age>               (postions 28-35)
        <dob></dob>               (postions 36-46)
    </input>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Positional data is not supported out of the box in WSO2 ESB. In order to convert the positional data to SOAP format, you need to write a custom Message Builder. When a message comes to WSO2 ESB, it needs to be build to a SOAP message as required by Axis2 engine. However, this needs to be done based on the message's content type.

I believe positional data comes to ESB as text/plain. In that case, you need to overwrite the existing default text/plain Builder and with your own implementation.

To write your own custom Builder, you need to extend your Builder from MessageFormatter [1], similar to in [2].

To add your custom Builder, add following to your axis2.xml.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/plain" class="<fully qualified path to Builder class>"/>
```

You can find more information on Builders and Formatters at [3].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/blob/master/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/transport/MessageFormatter.java

[2] https://github.com/wso2/wso2-axis2/blob/master/modules/transport/base/src/main/java/org/apache/axis2/format/PlainTextFormatter.java

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd">
    <fl:reader fields="firstname[100],lastname[26],age[3],dob[7]" />
</smooks-resource-list>

Comment: with the above configuration am able to convert, but one problem is its allowing only 136 characters.....If i give more than 136 characters, its not  converting into xml at the same time its not throwing any error as well.